# Discord.js: TypeError: confirmation.createMessageComponentCollector is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a ban command with confirmation thingy. I use buttons and
[MessageComponentCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) for it. However it fails and outputs the error. Here's my code:

```js
var bu1tton = new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setStyle(`SUCCESS`)
    .setEmoji(`872905464797605938`)
    .setLabel(`Proceed`)
    .setCustomId("proceed")
    var bt1 = new Discord.MessageButton()
    .setStyle("DANGER")
    .setEmoji(`872905464747286598`)
    .setLabel(`Cancel`)
    .setCustomId("back")
    var row = new Discord.MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents([bu1tton, bt1])
    const confirmation = interaction.followUp({
      embeds: [new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(`Are you sure?`).setColor("RED").setDescription(`Are you sure you want to ban **${target.user.tag}** for ${reason}?\nThis action will be automatically canceled in 10 seconds if you do not select any option.`).setFooter(interaction.guild.name)],
      components: [row]
      })
    const filter = ( inter ) => inter.user.id === interaction.user.id
    const collector = confirmation.createMessageComponentCollector({ filter, time: 10000 })

    collector.on('collect', async interaction => {
      if(interaction.customId === "proceed") {
      interaction.deferReply()
      await interaction.followUp({
      content: `**${interaction.user.tag}** banned **${target.user.tag}**.\nReason: *${reason}*.`
      })
      const reportChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(log_channel)
      const messageLink = `https://discord.com/channels/${interaction.guild.id}/${interaction.channel.id}/${interaction.id}`;
      let logchat = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(`${interaction.user.tag} (${interaction.user.id})`, interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setDescription(`**<:target:890913045126213633> Member:** ${target.user} (${target.user.id})\n**<:law:913487126576914502> Action:** Ban\n**<:decision:890913045537235005> Reason:** ${reason}\n**<:link:907511618097803284> Link:** [Click here](${messageLink})`)
      .setColor('RED')
      .setFooter(`ID: ${uuidv4()}`)
      .setTimestamp();
      const log = await reportChannel.send({
        embeds: [logchat]
      })

      const data = log.embeds[0]

      let dmembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("You have been banned from Rice Farm #11")
        .setDescription(`If you find this ban abusive or wrong, please proceed to [Ban Appeal page](https://ricesupport.brizy.site/).`)
        .addField("Moderator", `${interaction.user}`)
        .addField("Reason", `${reason}`)
        .setColor("RED")
        .setFooter(`${data.footer.text}`)
        .setTimestamp();

      await target.send({
        embeds: [dmembed]
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
      await target.ban({
        reason: `Banned by ${interaction.user.tag} | Reason: ${reason}`,
        days: num
      }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
        if(interaction.customId === "back") {
          interaction.deferReply()
          interaction.message.delete()
        }
    })

    collector.on('end', async interaction => {

    })
```

It sends the embed with components, but the collector obviously won't create.

Here's the full error:

```
[Error Handling System] Unhandled Rejection/Catch
TypeError: confirmation.createMessageComponentCollector is not a function
    at Object.run (/PC/184395345943/slash/Moderation/ban.js:114:36) Promise {
  <rejected> TypeError: confirmation.createMessageComponentCollector is not a function
      at Object.run (/PC/184395345943/slash/Moderation/ban.js:114:36)
}
```

I tried changing `confirmation.createMessageComponentCollector(...)` line to `confirmation.message.createMessageComponentCollector(...)`, but it output almost the same error:
`confirmation.message.createMessageComponentCollector() - undefined`

This made me confusing. Thank you in advance! <3

Comment: You need to look at what that `confirmation` really is. You can use `console.log` or step through your code in the debugger. Perhaps `interaction.followUp` is an async function and you need to `await` on it?

Comment: @tromgy this did help! you should post it as an answer so you it can get marked as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`followUp` returns a `Promise <(Message|APIMessage )>`, see for example this [doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/SelectMenuInteraction?scrollTo=followUp). So you need to `await` on it:

```
const confirmation = await interaction.followUp({
...
```